# image src= var error

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a variable which has the link to an image. But then it needs to be used in HTML. I made a fiddle with a basic copy of what im doing. If you could tell me how to fix it and why this doesnt work that would help a lot. Thanks :)

https://jsfiddle.net/w8r3gg0p/6/

JS:

```
var img = 'https://i.imgur.com/Njtsuv6.jpg';

document.getElementById('image').src = "img";
```

HTML:

```
<img id='image' src=' '>
```

Comment: It should be `).src = img;`

Comment: Putting double quotes around it stops it being a variable and turns it into a string literal.

Comment: You are setting img as a String where it is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with jQuery

```
<img id='image' src='' />

<script>
   var img = 'https://i.imgur.com/Njtsuv6.jpg';
   $('#image').attr('src', img);
</script>
```

This will change your image source dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotation marks.

change:

```
document.getElementById('image').src = "img";
```

to:

```
document.getElementById('image').src = img;
```